# Как сделать так,что при вводе нужного пароля пользователя false менялось на true и его перекидывало на другую страницу?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: Пока есть только это,не знаю как с этим работать]

вообще не понимаю как это сделать, в ютубе и интернете ничего такого не нашёл

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: *"в ютубе и интернете ничего такого не нашёл"* --- ну тогда читай книги по основам языка.